# Why does connected not imply locally connected?

Tags: general-topology

The terms used is based on the definition given in Munkres’ Topology. In the book, he claims that the Topologist sine curve is connected but not locally connected. He opines that it is connected since $S=\{x \times sin(1/x) | x\in (0,1]\}$ is connected and hence closure of S which is the topologist sine curve is connected, which I agree. He then claims that the topologist sine curve is not locally connected, which I am not too convinced.

My point of view is that if a set is connected, then every point in the set is contained in a connected neighbourhood which therefore satisfies the condition of being locally connected. In short, connected implies locally connected, thus the topologist sine curve is locally connected. Can someone enlighten me what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: To get the proper font and spacing for $\sin$, use `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: For a locally connected space, every neighbourhood (however small) of any point must contain a connected neighborhood of that point.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue in my statement is that the definition of locally connected holds for ANY neighbourhood, whereas the neighhbourhood I have defined for the set to be locally connected is only one specific neighbourhood( only along the topological sine curve). Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the definition. If a space is locally connected, then for every point $x$, each neighborhood of $x$ must *contain* a connected neighborhood (of $x$). In other words, the property must hold no matter how closely you zoom in near the point. For the topologist's sine curve, the global connectedness comes from the fact that you can take the "long way around" the loop. On a small scale, you cannot traverse the problem area since you can't go around.

Obviously that was informal, but its basically the right idea.

Comment: Also this answer should probably have a picture, but I'm being lazy. I'm picturing the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ along with the origin with a quotient joining $(0,0)$ and $(1/\pi,0)$, for example. You can play around with variations like this to get other counterexamples. (To be honest, it's not worth spending too much time on since you rarely encounter these pathological spaces unless you go looking.)

Comment: Intuitively, I think your idea makes sense. But on a small scale, I technically can construct a connected neighborhood about any point, where the neighbourhood is the points along the topologist sine curve so it is locally connected. Is that right?

Comment: You can find a connected neighborhood at every point yes — just take the whole space. If that were allowed, though, there wouldn't be any point to local connectedness. You need the property to hold for every neighborhood of the point.

Comment: Also to be clear, the issue is when you zoom in near $(0,0)$. The space looks like infinitely many vertical lines that are parallel.

Comment: If we zoom in near $(0,0)$, and construct a e-ball about this point, there is still a connected neighbourhood $U$ as long as I consider $U$ as the set of points lying along the curve. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the whole space is connected, wouldn't it also mean that the neighborhood of any point be connected? Or at the very least, we can construct such a neighbourhood by accounting for the set of points lying along the curve (if we can somehow rigorously define it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144875/discussion-between-lel-and-pancini).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If a neighborhood is just two parallel lines, for example, it is not a connected neighborhood. In that case, you can zoom in to the particular piece which contains $x$. For $\sin(1/x)$, there are infinitely many condensed parallel lines. No matter how close you zoom in, they will still be there.

Comment: So basically there is no way I can give a well-defined connected neighbourhood containing (0,0) without touching adjacent 'parallel lines'. If that's the case I think I understand it